# Give feed back to user when AsyncTask failes

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am sending Email using AsyncTask:

```
class AsyncSendEmail extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

private Exception exception;
Session session;

public AsyncSendEmail(Session _session)
{
    session = _session;
}

protected String doInBackground(String... parms) {
    try {

            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);   
            DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(parms[1].getBytes(), "text/plain"));   
            message.setSender(new InternetAddress(parms[2]));   
            message.setSubject(parms[0]);   
            message.setDataHandler(handler);   
            if (parms[2].indexOf(',') > 0)   
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(parms[2]));   
            else  
                message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(parms[2]));   
            Transport.send(message);  
            return "SUC";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "FLD";
    }
}
```

The methos invocation:

```
public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception 
{   
    new AsyncSendEmail(session).execute(subject,body,sender,recipients);
}
```

When my "doInBackground" method excecutes and failes i want to alert the user using Notification.

How can i do this? how can i catch the Exception from the method invocation?

Or how can i get a Context so i can show a notification?

Comment: you can make a flag that indicate if the sending failed and in onPostExecute check the flag and make the notification

Answer (score 0):

In your AsyncTask:

```
private Exception lastException = null;

protected String doInBackground(String... parms) {
    try {

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);   
        DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(parms[1].getBytes(), "text/plain"));   
        message.setSender(new InternetAddress(parms[2]));   
        message.setSubject(parms[0]);   
        message.setDataHandler(handler);   
        if (parms[2].indexOf(',') > 0)   
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(parms[2]));   
        else  
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(parms[2]));   
        Transport.send(message);  
        return "SUC";
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    /*
    * Remember this exception for when onPostExecute is called.
    */
    this.lastException = e;
    return "FLD";
}
```

}

Then check the state of lastException in onPostExecute():

```
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    if (lastException != null) {
        // Do the notification here. You might need to set a context field on this
        // AsyncTask prior to invoking it if you need this here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should pass a context parameter in your constructor:

```
private Context mContext;

public AsyncSendEmail(Context context, Session _session)
{
  mContext = context;
  session = _session;
}
```

Then you can refer to `mContext` in the class whenever you need context (such as to create a notification).

To store the success/fail, I would add a boolean property (maybe `mSuccess`) to the class and set it to true once you have detected (within `doInBackground()`) that a message has been successfully sent.

Then, override `onPostExecute()`:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
  if (mSuccess) {
    // Do something when the email has been successfully sent
  }
  else {
    // Show error notification
  }
}
```

Remember, `doInBackground()` is executed on a background thread, but `onPostExecute()` is executed on the main/UI thread after `doInBackground()` has finished running.

Answer (score 0):

The onPostExecute() method of AsyncTask is is used to provide an output to the user about what happens within the AsyncTask. Since you cannot pass on an Exception to onPostEexecute() (well, theoretically, you could - but it's obviously more important to pass the result which is not an exception), the best option in your case would be to set a flag depending on whether the method passed or failed and then read this flag in onPostExecute() and then proceed to do whatever it is that you need to do.